# Setting value by slicing index and conditional rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Trying to set a col 'X' value by slicing on multindex and also accounting for a column 'Z' conditional value. I can set the col 'X' value pretty easily, but I'm getting stuck trying to figure out the conditional.

```
import pandas as pd

FOOBAR = (['foo','foo','foo','foo','bar','bar','bar','bar'])
NUM1 = ([5,5,6,6,8,8,5,5])
NUM2 = ([1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1])
NUM3 = ([1001,1002,1002,1002,1003,1004,1004,1005])

#build and name index using data
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([FOOBAR,NUM1,NUM2,NUM3], 
                                  names=['iFOOBAR','iNUM1','iNUM2','iNUM3'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   'Y': [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
                   'Z': [ 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7],
                   'FL': [0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.1,0.1]
                   }, index=index)

df.sortlevel(inplace=True)
idx = pd.IndexSlice

#original df
#                            FL  X  Y  Z
#iFOOBAR iNUM1 iNUM2 iNUM3              
#bar     5     1     1004   0.1  6  G  7
#                    1005   0.1  7  H  7
#        8     3     1003   0.4  4  E  5
#                    1004   0.4  5  F  6
#foo     5     1     1001   0.1  0  A  1
#                    1002   0.1  1  B  2
#        6     2     1002   0.2  2  C  2
#                    1002   0.2  3  D  4

#set value in 'X' based on index
newdf = df.loc[idx['foo',5,1,:], idx['X']] = 999

#new df
#                            FL    X  Y  Z
#iFOOBAR iNUM1 iNUM2 iNUM3                
#bar     5     1     1004   0.1    6  G  7
#                    1005   0.1    7  H  7
#        8     3     1003   0.4    4  E  5
#                    1004   0.4    5  F  6
#foo     5     1     1001   0.1  999  A  1
#                    1002   0.1  999  B  2
#        6     2     1002   0.2    2  C  2
#                    1002   0.2    3  D  4

#set value in 'X' base on index and 'Z' == 2 ???
#nextdf = df.loc[idx['foo',5,1,:], idx['Z'== 2]], 'X' = 999

#next df: desired output
#                            FL    X  Y  Z
#iFOOBAR iNUM1 iNUM2 iNUM3                
#bar     5     1     1004   0.1    6  G  7
#                    1005   0.1    7  H  7
#        8     3     1003   0.4    4  E  5
#                    1004   0.4    5  F  6
#foo     5     1     1001   0.1    0  A  1
#                    1002   0.1  999  B  2
#        6     2     1002   0.2    2  C  2
#                    1002   0.2    3  D  4
```

Comment: I think you want to use a mask for the conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: (one line)

```
df.loc[idx[:,5,1,(df['Z'] == 2)],idx['X']] = 999
df


                           FL    X  Y  Z
iFOOBAR iNUM1 iNUM2 iNUM3                
bar     5     1     1004   0.1    6  G  7
                    1005   0.1    7  H  7
        8     3     1003   0.4    4  E  5
                    1004   0.4    5  F  6
foo     5     1     1001   0.1    0  A  1
                    1002   0.1  999  B  2
        6     2     1002   0.2    2  C  2
                    1002   0.2    3  D  4
In [126]:
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually kind of tricky.  Feels like there could be a better way - but here's one approach that depends on a little knowledge of the indexing internals - building up the set of locations that that meet your criteria, then passing that all to `iloc`.

```
In [80]: cond1 = df.index.get_locs(idx['foo',5, 1, :])

In [81]: cond2, = (df['Z'] == 2).nonzero()

In [82]: row_indexer = pd.Index(cond1).intersection(cond2)

In [83]: row_indexer
Out[83]: Int64Index([5], dtype='int64')

In [84]: col_indexer = df.columns.get_loc('X')

In [85]: df.iloc[row_indexer, col_indexer] = 999

In [90]: df
Out[90]: 
                            FL    X  Y  Z
iFOOBAR iNUM1 iNUM2 iNUM3                
bar     5     1     1004   0.1    6  G  7
                    1005   0.1    7  H  7
        8     3     1003   0.4    4  E  5
                    1004   0.4    5  F  6
foo     5     1     1001   0.1    0  A  1
                    1002   0.1  999  B  2
        6     2     1002   0.2    2  C  2
                    1002   0.2    3  D  4
```

Comment: Would have never thought to do it like this, props on the method. However, it is messing up relationships somewhere in my datasource. I need to dig into it further to understand exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

If the DataFrame, `df`, had a unique index, then you could use

```
index1 = df.loc[df['Z'] == 2].index
index2 = df.loc[idx['foo',5,1,:]].index
df.loc[index1.intersection(index2), 'X'] = 999
```

Since your `df` does not have a unique index, you could create a faux index column, and then proceed similarly:

```
df['index'] = np.arange(len(df))
index1 = df.loc[df['Z'] == 2, 'index']
index2 = df.loc[idx['foo',5,1,:], 'index']
df.ix[np.intersect1d(index1, index2), 'X'] = 999
df = df.drop('index', axis=1)
print(df)
```

yields

```
                            FL    X  Y  Z
iFOOBAR iNUM1 iNUM2 iNUM3                
bar     5     1     1004   0.1    6  G  7
                    1005   0.1    7  H  7
        8     3     1003   0.4    4  E  5
                    1004   0.4    5  F  6
foo     5     1     1001   0.1    0  A  1
                    1002   0.1  999  B  2
        6     2     1002   0.2    2  C  2
                    1002   0.2    3  D  4
```

---

Note that [chrisb's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38880451/190597) is more efficient because it does not generate
sub-DataFrames. It prepares ordinal indexers and then cuts once.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

```
mask = df.loc[idx[:],idx['Z']] == 2
df.loc[idx[mask,5,1,:],idx['X']] = 999
```

Comment: But then you are not really restricting the first index level to `'foo'`. It is just a lucky coincidence that `iFOOBAR` is `foo` when `Z == 2`.